# WordPress Database Keeps crashing frequently

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce, server

I have a website that is using WordPress + WooCommerce to manage an e-commerce website. Right now we are using a plugin called: "WP All Import" with the WooCommerce Add-on to Import from a .CSV file all the product data (SKU, Title, Description, Price, Image link, etc).

So the problem is that when we run the import it frequently crashes giving error message
[This is the error that keeps showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leC5L.png)

We asked to our host and they answer with the following:

"
We are sorry for the server issues. The website requests are causing the MariaDB to allocate all CPU resources and making the server restart to kill the processes
ov 25 13:29:35 server mysqld: 2020-11-25 13:29:35 140531759913152 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.2.36-MariaDB) starting as process 22045 ...
Nov 25 13:29:35 server mysqld: 2020-11-25 13:29:35 140531759913152 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 524288 (request: 524423)

top - 13:33:21 up 1:02, 2 users, load average: 9.48, 10.41, 10.28
Tasks: 145 total, 24 running, 119 sleeping, 0 stopped, 2 zombie
%Cpu(s): 85.3 us, 14.5 sy, 0.0 ni, 0.2 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
KiB Mem : 4194304 total, 1292680 free, 2622632 used, 278992 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 524288 total, 338664 free, 185624 used. 1390602 avail Mem
"

Checking with tools like GTMetrix, we are not as good as we have to be in performance, getting an "E" score with the most important thing to change the amount of DOM elements (Now aprox. 2100)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, this is partially sounding like a MariaDB bug which [should be reported](https://jira.mariadb.org/) however more substantial information need to occur namely.  What WooCommerce/WP All Import versions? Does this occur with a smaller CSV? Did this succeed before (possibly with an earlier MariaDB version)? Can you include a 'SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST' SQ output? What does the complete mariadb error log look like? Or will all CPU used - [running backtrace](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/#getting-backtraces-from-a-running-mysqld-process-with-gdb-on-linux)?

Comment: happy to continue a conversation on a [JIRA bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/) or [MariaDB community chat](https://mariadb.zulipchat.com/)

Comment: I've also run up a sandbox on the 'WP All Import' site where after Time Elapsed 00:25:45
only Processed 1677 of 2455 records WooCommerce records are imported.

Comment: I have this [WooCommerce SystemReport](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjnhbwaing0t3s5/woo%20status.txt?dl=0)

It was working before, at least it didn't crash every 10 records

We are using a VPS and as well we have StackPatch DNS and WAF

Comment: The details *requested* on a JIRA bug report please.